# hpple elements within elements

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, html-parsing, hpple

I have been using Hpple to parse some html in my iphone application (iOS5.1).  I have searched for all 'td' elements within a table row.  I am iterating through each of these elements, and for the most part I can retrieve all the information I need from the element, e.g.

```
[element objectForKey:@"rowspan"];
```

But one of the values I need is within the td:

```
<tr>
<td rowspan="3">  //This is my element
   <div>
      <a>link text</a>  //The link text is what I want
   </div>
</td>
</tr>
```

Is there a way of getting the 'a' tags within my element, I have tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
[[[element firstChild] firstChild] content];
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out... The Xcode debugger wasn't as helpful compared to some other IDEs I work with, but once I found the 'print description' option I was able to see what was going on...

I was getting an error 'Invalid CFStringRef' when I tried `[element content]` and when I tried `[[element firstChild] content]` it printed "\n" which was not what I was expecting. Anyway, this is probably a really long way to get what I wanted, but this was my solution...

```
NSArray* childrenArray = [element children];
TFHppleElement *childElement = [childrenArray objectAtIndex:1];
TFHppleElement *newChildElement = [[childElement children] objectAtIndex:1];
NSString *name = [[newChildElement firstChild] content];  //This is the content I wanted
```